# Sphinx quickstart limited options

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx

I'm following severall tutorials for the sphinx documentation. I.e. this one here:

https://medium.com/@richdayandnight/a-simple-tutorial-on-how-to-document-your-python-project-using-sphinx-and-rinohtype-177c22a15b5b

But whenever I use the sphinx-quickstart command I don't get all options showed in this tutorial and other ones. 
I just get these ones:

```
Selected root path: .

You have two options for placing the build directory for Sphinx output.
Either, you use a directory "_build" within the root path, or you separate
"source" and "build" directories within the root path.
> Separate source and build directories (y/n) [n]: y

The project name will occur in several places in the built documentation.
> Project name: Project Example
> Author name(s): Hello World
> Project release []: 0.1

If the documents are to be written in a language other than English,
you can select a language here by its language code. Sphinx will then
translate text that it generates into that language.

For a list of supported codes, see
https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-language.
> Project language [en]:

Creating file .\source\conf.py.
Creating file .\source\index.rst.
Creating file .\Makefile.
Creating file .\make.bat.
```

Why are the other options missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the linked tutorial, Sphinx 1.7.5 is used. In Sphinx 2.0.0, the sphinx-quickstart procedure was simplified. Fewer questions are now asked.

Reference: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/4148.